# Am I using reduce method in a wrong way?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, reduce

In this problem, i trying to sum up the values inside an array of each object.

I expect the output of

> [{   name: "Bob",   scores: [75] }, {   name: "Bill",   scores: [95]
>   }, {   name: "Charlie",   scores: [95] }]

```
function winner(c1, c2, c3) {
  var customerArr = [];
  customerArr.push(c1, c2, c3);
  // console.log(customerArr);

  customerArr.forEach(customer => {
    customer.scores = customer.scores.reduce(function(total, scores) {
      return total + scores;
    }, 0)
    // console.log(Array.isArray(customer.scores))
  });

  return customerArr;
}

c1 = {
  "name": "Bob",
  "scores": [10, 65]
}

c2 = {
  "name": "Bill",
  "scores": [90, 5]
}

c3 = {
  "name": "Charlie",
  "scores": [40, 55]
};

console.log(winner(c1, c2, c2));
```

O/P:

> TypeError: customerArr[i].scores.reduce is not a function

Comment: Issue is here: `console.log(winner(c1, c2, c2));` Notice last arg. It should have been `c3` but is `c2`. And the reason for the error is the fact that you are overriding `scores` from array of scores to total

Comment: Please check the snippet. It gives proper output

Comment: Also updating questions based on comments will make the comment void. Do not do that

Comment: Yes, you are right, i should have passed c1, c2, c3. Now it worked!!

Comment: Yeah, Ok bro, i won't do it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var c1 = {
  "name": "Bob",
  "scores": [10, 65]
}

var c2 = {
  "name": "Bill",
  "scores": [90, 5]
}

var c3 = {
  "name": "Charlie",
  "scores": [40, 55]
};
var custom = [c1, c2, c3];

function winner(customerArr){
customerArr.forEach(customer => {
    customer.scores = customer.scores.reduce(function(total, scores) {
      return total + scores;
    }, 0)});

    return customerArr;
};

console.log(winner(custom));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass c1, c2 and c3 respectively as the parameters, you will get the correct output. However, if you call the function again, you will get the same error since the object will be mutated and "scores" will not be an array anymore.

You can try the following:

```js
console.log(winner(Object.assign({}, c1),Object.assign({}, c2),Object.assign({}, c3)));
```

This will not mutate the original objects.

Answer (score -1):

You pass same object as second and third parameter

```
function winner(...customers) {
  customers.forEach((customer) => {
    customer.scores = customer.scores.reduce(function(total, score) {
      return total + score;
    }, 0);
  });

  return customers;
}

var c1 = {
  "name": "Bob",
  "scores": [10, 65]
}

var c2 = {
  "name": "Bill",
  "scores": [90, 5]
}

var c3 = {
  "name": "Charlie",
  "scores": [40, 55]
};

console.log(winner(c1, c2, c3)); // <-- (c1, c2, c2) => (c1, c2, c3);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your objects are mutated and you put c2 object twice in the winner function.

So c2 first time is in the reduce function is:

```
{
  "name": "Bill",
  "scores": [90, 5]
}
```

Second time its:

```
{
  "name": "Bill",
  "scores": 95
}
```

And you can't call reduce on a integere function. So it's giving you that error.

If you change `console.log(winner(c1, c2, c2));` to `console.log(winner(c1, c2, c3));` it would work fine.

I suggest to not alter the object you retrieve in your function. But make a new object. That is the functional programming way.

```
function winner(c1, c2, c3) {
  var customerArr = [];
  customerArr.push(c1, c2, c3);
  // console.log(customerArr);

  const newCustomerArr = customerArr.map(customer => ({
    ...customer,
    scores: customer.scores.reduce(function(total, scores) {
      return total + scores;
    }, 0)
  }));

  return newCustomerArr;
}

c1 = {
  "name": "Bob",
  "scores": [10, 65]
}

c2 = {
  "name": "Bill",
  "scores": [90, 5]
}

c3 = {
  "name": "Charlie",
  "scores": [40, 55]
};

console.log(winner(c1, c2, c2));
```